# Finding Mass of Star with only Luminosity

Tags: fundamental-astronomy, luminosity

Estimate the mass of the star given this formula:

$$\frac{L}{L_\mathrm{\odot}} = \left(\frac{M}{M_\mathrm{\odot}}\right)^{3.5}$$

Given $L= 2.752\times10^{28}\,\mathrm{W}$, how do I find the mass of the star?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I guess $L_\mathrm{sun}$  and $M_\mathrm{sun}$ are values for our sun? If so all you need is a simple rearrangeing of the given formula

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is more or less an algebra question, not an astronomy one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like homework (correct me if that assumption is wrong, as you may want a somewhat different answer then.), so here is a **hint:**

Clean up the equation first, to something that looks more like an equation for mass:

$$\frac{L}{L_{sun}} = \left(\frac{M}{M_{sun}}\right)^{3.5}$$

$$\left(\frac{L}{L_{sun}}\right)^{\frac{1}{3.5}} = \frac{M}{M_{sun}}$$